# Angular 8 - HTTP POST send password with special sign encoding problem

Tags: angular, angular-cli

my POST request looks like this:

```
const loginParam = new HttpParams()
.set('Username', 'myUser')
.set('Password', ':(7vHa%+_(Tbc+m@');

this.http.post('/post', loginParam).subscribe(value => {
  console.log('success');
}, error => {
  console.log('error');
});
```

The server replies (status code 500) that the login was unsuccessful. Can it be that the password is not sent correctly? In the following a snippet from the devtools:

View Form Data (the password seems to be wrong - the plus sign has disappeared)

[image: view form data]

Is it possible that the server gets an incorrect password? Everything works without problems with Postman.

Comment: Do you have access to the server component? So you could try to encode your password with `encodeURI()` before sending the password and decode it in the server component before you hand it over to the real login method.

Comment: @JohnArcher
Unfortunately I have no access to the server.

Comment: Ok. Does this help you? -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/22671551 And here is a post with a similar problem (unfortunately no anwer): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42023170/angular2-http-post-request-parameters-prevent-encoding-the-special-characters

Comment: @JohnArcher Thanks for the hints. I found a post that solves my problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53546691/preserving-plus-sign-in-urlencoded-http-post-request

Answer (score 1):

I found a post that solves my problem:

[Preserving + (Plus Sign) in URLEncoded Http Post request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53546691/preserving-plus-sign-in-urlencoded-http-post-request)

Now, everything works like a charme.